# Sum of child nodes in accounting hierarchy in django/python

Tags: python, django, recursion

How do you create a sum of child nodes into a a parent node for multiple levels in an accounting hierarchy with Python/Django?

I currently have an app which displays the sum of individual accounts, but these values are not added to parent level accounts.

The app has the following models:

```
from django.db import models

class accounts(models.Model):
    account_nr = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_parent_nr = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class transactions(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_ID = models.ForeignKey(accounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    debit_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    credit_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Some sample data is:

```
account_nr    account_name     account_parent_nr
1000          current assets   null
1001          cash             1000
1002          bank             1000
1010          debtors          1000
1011          debtor 1         1010
1012          debtor 2         1010
3000          stock            null
3010          category 1       3000
3011          product a        3010
3012          product b        3010     
...
0010          equity           null
0011          owner x          0010
0012          owner y          0010
```

Sample data for transactions would be:

```
transaction_id    account_id    debit_value    credit_value
1                 1001          100            0
1                 0011          0              100
2                 1002          100            0
2                 0011          0              100
3                 1011          100            0
3                 0011          0              100
4                 1012          100            0
4                 0011          0              100
5                 3011          50             0
5                 3012          50             0
5                 0012          0              100
```

The following view is used:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Sum

from .models import accounts, transactions

def home(request):
    account_query = accounts.objects.all() \
    .annotate(Sum('transactions__debit_value')) \
    .annotate(Sum('transactions__credit_value')) \
    .order_by('account_nr')
    args = {'account_queryx': account_query}
    return render(request, 'home.html', args)
```

And the following template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Omschrijving</th> 
      <th>Debit</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
    {% for account_query in account_queryx %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ account_query.account_nr }}</td>
      <td>{{ account_query.account_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ account_query.transactions__debit_value__sum}}</td>
      <td>{{ account_query.transactions__credit_value__sum }}</td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I now end up with something like this:

```
acount_id    account_name    debit    credit
1000         current assets  null     null
1001         cash            100      0
1002         bank            100      0
1010         debtors         null     null
1011         debtor 1        100      0
1012         debtor 2        100      0
3000         stock           null     null
3010         category 1      null     null
3011         product a       50       0
3012         product b       50       0       
...
0010         equity          null     null
0011         owner x         0        400
0012         owner y         0        100
```

What I want to end up with is that the values which now show null are summations of child nodes. I prefer to implement a solution into my views.py.

I have searched for theory that could help me with this. I have found that recursive summation could help, however I struggle to get this into working code. I don't understand what algorithm I should use to create a sum based on account numbers/parent-child relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're envisioning something that requires a more complex data model that can tell which specific sub-accounts are children of a parent account, and a correspondingly more complicated query to subtotal those when you hit the database.

Lacking this, I'd suggest you get the raw data basically as you are doing presently, then iterate over it to build a presentation-ready data set that you can format in the view with the subtotals...

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Sum

from .models import accounts, transactions

def home(request):

    # Get the raw account balances

    account_query_raw = accounts.objects.all() \
    .annotate(Sum('transactions__debit_value')) \
    .annotate(Sum('transactions__credit_value')) \
    .order_by('account_nr')

    # Build the updated dataset with account sums

    account_query = [ ]
    cur_parent_index = None

    for account in account_query_raw:

        account_query.append( account )

        if not account_query.transactions__debit_value__sum:

            # new parent account...
            # set null sums in parent records to zero

            current_parent_index = len( account_query ) -1
            parent = account_query[ cur_parent_index ]

            parent.transactions__debit_value = 0
            parent.transactions__credit_value = 0

        elif current_parent_index:

            # if we have a current parent account,
            # include this account in the parent's sum

            parent = account_query[ cur_parent_index ]

            parent.transactions__debit_value__sum += \
                account.transactions__debit_value__sum

            parent.transactions__credit_value__sum += \
                account.transactions__credit_value__sum

    args = {'account_queryx': account_query}

    return render(request, 'home.html', args)
```

There's often a tendency to think you want to do all of this sort of data manipulation at the database, but if you've got to pull all the result records back from the database to render anyway, there's not really much of a performance issue with manipulating them directly in Python into exactly what you need.